# Can't find variable Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

Using Polymer 1.x I've tried to create a dom module like following:

```
<dom-module id="template-me">
    <template>
        <!-- local DOM styles -->
        <style>
        div { color: red }
        </style>
        <div>This is local DOM</div>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer({is: "template-me"});
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

The problem is that when running I get the error "Can't find variable Polymer"? Does anyone knows why?

Comment: Is that the entire pages code?

Answer (score 1):

If that is all the code, you are missing the link element that should be before the module.

```
<link rel="import" href="../polymer/polymer.html">
<dom-module id="template-me">
    <template>
      ...
```

Comment: I already have setup <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"> without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

Double check your polymer import code and the path. Here is a working demo of `template-me` using `polymer.html` from repo.

```html
<html>  
<head>

  <title>Template me</title>
  
  <link rel="import" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/download/polymer-cdn/1.0.1/lib/polymer/polymer.html">  

  
</head>
<body class="fullbleed">

<template-me></template-me>

<dom-module id="template-me">
  <template>
   <style>
        div { color: red }
        </style>
        <div>This is local DOM</div>
    

  </template>
              
  <script>
    Polymer({
      is : "template-me"
      });
    </script>
    
</dom-module>

</body>
</html>
```